# How to plot without the excess space in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

It seems that ggplot2 will always plot a geom with an excess space.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = rep(c(3.0, 3.1, 4.0), c(5, 10, 4)))
ggplot(df, aes(x)) + geom_bar()
```

And the result plot is just like this:

[image: barplot in ggplot2]

You can see though the minimum x is 3.0, the plot will also show the space where x is less than 3.0. Similarly, the maximum x is 4.0 but the plot will also show the space where x is greater than 4.0. The excess space will show in the red box below:

[image: barplot in ggplot2 with excess space in red box]

If I set the limitation of the x axis, the spaces remain and throw a warning:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x)) + geom_bar() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(3.0, 4.0))
```

```
Warning message:
Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

[image: set limitation]

In other plot, this situation also exsists:

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p + geom_point()
```

[image: point plot]

So is there a method to cut these excess space? The finally results may seem like this:

[image: modified 1]

[image: modified 2]

And the space in the red box will be removed.

Comment: By default ggplot2 expands the axis. To get rid of this excess space you have to set the expand argument in scale_x/y_xxx via ggplot2::expansion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest next approach with `expand` in `scale_x_continuous()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
df <- data.frame(x = rep(c(3.0, 3.1, 4.0), c(5, 10, 4)))
#Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x)) + geom_bar()+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.01,0))
```

Output:

[image]

You can further tune that option in order to modify the mentioned space. With `scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))` all space will removed:

```
#Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x)) + geom_bar()+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

Output:

[image]